# Getting value from a combo box in a table problem

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a table that's being populated from a database. you can edit the table then update the database with the new data. I have this:

```
    def populate(self):
        tablerow = 0
        rowcount = 0

        self.ui.widget_unass_fights.clearContents()
        self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setRowCount(0)
        for row in x:
            rowcount += 1
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setRowCount(rowcount)
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])))
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[5])))
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 8, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[8])))
            combobox1 = QComboBox()
            combobox1.clear()

            for j in self.plane_list_combo:
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
                combobox1.addItem(j)
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setCellWidget(tablerow, 1, combobox1)
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(tablerow, 1).setCurrentText(row[1])

            combobox2 = QComboBox()
            combobox2.clear()
            combobox2.addItem("")
            combobox3 = QComboBox()
            combobox3.clear()
            combobox3.addItem("")

            for j in self.pilot_list_combo:
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setItem(tablerow, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(""))
                combobox2.addItem(j)
                combobox3.addItem(j)
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setCellWidget(tablerow, 6, combobox2)
                self.ui.widget_unass_fights.setCellWidget(tablerow, 7, combobox3)
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(tablerow, 6).setCurrentText(row[6])
            self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(tablerow, 7).setCurrentText(row[7])

            tablerow += 1
        print(self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(0, 1).currentText())

    def update(self)
        rowcount = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.rowCount()
        print(self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(0, 1).currentText())
        
        for i in range(rowcount):
            flight_id = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 0).text()
            flight_reg = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(i, 1).currentText()
            desc = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 2).text()
            date = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 3).text()
            etd = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 4).text()
            flight_time = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 5).text()
            pilot = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(i, 6).currentText()
            co_pilot = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(i, 7).currentText()
            max_pax = self.ui.widget_unass_fights.item(i, 8).text()
```

columns 1, 6, and 7 are combo boxes

When I tried running the update function I got the error:

self.ui.widget_unass_fights.cellWidget(i, 1).currentText()
AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'currentText'

so I put in the 2 print commands to try to find out why. the print command in the populate function works, but the print command in the update function doesn't, they are copy and paste of each other, they should both work right? what am I doing wrong?

EDIT - after fiddling around I found that It will only let me call the last row of the table, none of the others.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to come up with a minimal standalone code that reproduces the problem to increase the chance to get an useful answer

Comment: @pygri after fiddling around I found that It will only let me call the last row of the table, none of the others.

Comment: @Ben: that's due to the for cycle, as you cannot set the same cell widget more than once (widgets cannot be shown multiple times): the widget will *always* be shown in the last (valid) cell for which you called `setCellWidget()`. If you want more combos, you need to create one for each cell. If you need further help, please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @musicamante That makes sense, thanks. I fixed it with exec("self.combobox1_" + str(tablerow) + "=" + "QComboBox()")
            getattr(self, "combobox1_{}".format(tablerow)).clear() to make a combo box for each round of the loop.